# CiviMail tokens to share the public mailing URL on social media

Tags: civimail, tokens

As a site admin using CiviMail/Mosaico, is there an easy way to add links to share the mailing content on social media?

I am guessing I could write HTML using a link such as:

```
http://twitter.com/share?text={mailing.subject-if-it-exists}&url={mailing.viewUrl}
```

and then also the equivalents for Facebook etc.

Are there extensions that already do this in a more user-friendly way? (I will write an extension otherwise, feedback welcome)

Comment: I've never seen such an extension myself.